# What happend if the divergence of a vector field is zero?

Tags: operator-theory, translation-request

I just want to be sure if I'm wrong or not, I want to know what happend for a vector fiel if his divergence is zero ?

Are the vectors have all the same lengh ? Or maybe are they all time parallel ?

PS : I read some questions about this on this site but none of the answers help me :/

Thank you

Comment: You could say that the flux entering a given closed surface is the same as the flux leaving.

Comment: For example: Suppose we have some incompressible fluid (water is a good approximation). Then if a quantity of water enters a given volume, like some imaginary box, then that same quantity must be leaving the box. So the water current has zero divergence.

Comment: Hum OK, and if I see some vectors on a map, how can I know if the field has a zero divergence or not ?

Comment: Hm, I don't know if that's possible. Do you have an example of a map like that?

Comment: @Shadock You can use  [field lines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_line#Divergence_and_curl)

Comment: I have not, but I revise my physics because I have some hard competitive exam (ENS, Centrale, Mînes etc...) I'm french, and in a papper I have this question, but there is no solution ...

Comment: @Shadock Hey, I'm having those exams too. :D I'm not from France, though.

Comment: You cannot see it by looking at a figure showing 1000 field vectors. The divergence sits in the derivatives ${\partial v_i\over\partial x_k}$ of the components of these vectors. Nevertheless the intuitive content of ${\rm div}\,v=0$ is easy to grasp.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter for me it's not easy to grasp ... :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagine that the vector field in question describes the velocity of fluid at a given point in a giant tank of fluid. In this instance, a net positive divergence over a solid region means that there is fluid flowing out of that region or, equivalently, that fluid is being produced within the region, a 'source' if you like. A net negative divergence, on the other hand, would mean that fluid is being sucked into that region, a 'sink' or 'drain', if you like.

If you think about what the formula for divergence is talking about, you'll see it's effectively asking "how much fluid is being 'produced' or 'sucked out' at this point?" similar to how the curl is asking "how much is the fluid circulating around this point?". If we sum over all the 'production' and 'suction' of a region (integrate the divergence over the region), then we get the the amount of fluid that's going through the boundary of that region (integrate the flux over the boundary), which exactly what the Divergence Theorem says. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

We are talking about a flow field $v$ which does not change in time; but the field vectors change from point to point. Consider a fixed point $p$ within this flow field and a  cube $C$ of side length $s\ll1$ centered at $p$. The net flux $\Phi$ of $v$ through the surface $\partial C$ of this cube  represents the amount of fluid produced within $C$ per second: This flux is the amount of outgoing fluid minus the amount of incoming fluid per second. When the flow field $v$ is homogeneous (i.e. constant in space) then this difference is zero. In order to compute $\Phi$ we compute approximatively the flux through the six faces of $C$ and obtain
$$\Phi\doteq\sum_{i=1}^3 \biggl(v_i\bigl(p_i+{s\over2}\bigr)-v_i\bigl(p_i-{s\over2}\bigr)\biggr)s^2\doteq\sum_{i=1}^3{\partial v_i\over\partial x_i}(p)s\  s^2={\rm vol}(C)\>\sum_{i=1}^3{\partial v_i\over\partial x_i}(p)\qquad(s\ll1)\ .$$
This can be interpreted as follows: There is some "production intensity" at work within $C$ that produces the amount
$${\rm div}\>v(p):=\sum_{i=1}^3{\partial v_i\over\partial x_i}(p)$$
of fluid per unit volume and second. This "production intensity" is called the *divergence* of $v$ at $p$. If this divergence is $\equiv0$ throughout the domain $\Omega$ of $v$ this means that no new fluid is produced anywhere, and this entails that for **any** body $B\subset\Omega$ the total flux through its surface $\partial B$ is zero.